# ChartJS: How to set fix width of tick scale in pixels for time scale

Tags: javascript, chart.js, primeng

It seems there is no answer provided for this question or probably such a question has been never asked.

Anyway, problem is that I have a table view which consists of columns corresponding each day (of a time-period, for example current month) with a value filled in (some measured data for a person on the day). I am using chartjs to display the trend/visual-representation of that under the table row detail view (e.g. user needs to click a row to see the chart). My MAIN goal is to do so that table columns (headers) and chart x-axis are aligned properly so they are visually in sync and therefore easier to read/visualize.

It seems for default case, table uses ~100+pixels to separate individual labels on x-axis (e.g. days shown as 01.01.2020      02.01.2020                                       31.01.2020

I would like to set a fix width between those labels so that it could be controlled. I would like them to be exactly 121 pixels wide or so but this is just an example. I might have to possibly use even larger or smaller size based on scenario.

Is there anyway to do it? Any help is highly appreciated. Please note that I am using PrimeNG for charts which uses essentially chartjs behind-the-scenes.